# Use django_filters to query a list that contains any item in query params

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I'm having a Django model that contains a JSON field to store a list, like so:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    tags = JSONField()
```

As such, a movie **mymovie** contains a list of tags, such as:

```
mymovie.tags = ["horror", "love", "adventure"].
```

And now, I want a query to fetch all movies having at least one tag of a list of tags, like so:

```
GET /movies?tags=horror,cowboy
```

In my previous example, the query will get mymovie, because it has **horror** in its tag, even if it doesn't have **cowboy**.

Using ***django_filters**, I managed to do it with the following implementation:

```
class CharInFilter(BaseInFilter, CharFilter):
    pass

class MovieFilter(FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ["tags"]

    tags = CharInFilter(method="tags_filter")

    def tags_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        # value will contain a list of tags, and we want any movie that at least one of
        # its tag is in the list of provided tags
        query = Q()
        for tag in value:
            query |= Q(
                tags__icontains=tag
            )
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(query)
    
        return queryset
```

It works, but it feels very hacky, and I won't be surprised if an ad hoc implementation of this exists.

Does someone have a better idea ?

Thank youuuu ^^

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: really ? I wonder why there isn't a field, a little like a BaseIn filter, that handles this operations in the framework, a sort of BaseInAny :)

Comment: What do you mean by "BaseIn"?

Comment: oups sorry, I should have sourced the reference, I meant this filter field type: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=baseinfilter#baseinfilter

Comment: Yes, you probably can create a custom `Filter` subclass that encapsulates this logic. The primary benefit is that it is then more general for any field on the model. This will just move the logic, not change it in any fundamental way, which is what I thought you were asking.

Comment: Okay ! In that case I'm okay ^^ I'll will implement this custom filter if I find the need of this behavior to be reusable elsewhere.